# Efficient algorithm for finding k largest elements with range of values

Tags: algorithm, range

Assume there is a list of elements each with a range, such that the value of the element would lie in the range. The ranges between elements may overlap. The exact value is unknown, but it can be calculated. What would be an optimal algorithm to select the elements with highest k values, such that the number of exact computations is minimum?

I have a very naive and straight-forward algorithm, but definitely this is not optimal.

1. Sort the ranges according to maximum range values.
2. Compute first k values.
3. Remove the elements for which the maximum range value is less than the value of the k^{th} highest value till now.
4. From the remaining elements, calculate the value of the element with the maximum range value and update highest k list. If there are no remaining elements, then stop.
5. Go to 3

Comment: Your approach actually seems pretty reasonable.  One possible improvement could be to optimize your sorting basis - I think ideally you'd wan to sort by expected value, not maximum possible value.  For example, if the value is uniformly distributed between `min` and `max`, you could sort by `(min+max)/2`.

Comment: There is some ambiguity with your question: do you wish to `find elements with highest k values` or do you wish to `find k largest elements`? Replace k with a real number like 5 and read and decide which one you need and correct the question accordingly.

Comment: I want to find k elements whose actual values are the highest.

Answer (score 0):

This can be improved without leaving the realm of naivité:

- It is assured, that an element A, where the range-max is lower than the range-min of an element B also has a lower real value. So you drop all elements, that have a range-max lower than the 5th highest range-min. This leaves you with a much smaller list: If your original list is long (i.e.: Disk-based) you most likely can reduce it to a mem-based version. In addition to that, the selection run will most likely leave you with this sub-list already sorted.
- If still necessary, sort the smaller list
- (*) Now cycle similar to your original algorithm:

  - remove the highest-max element from the list and calculate the real value for it, ordering it into a sorted working list
  - move all values, that have range-max below this value from the current list to a secondary list, keeping the sortedness
- This gives you an even shorter working list, that is assured to contain the highest values

  - if this has enough entries, chose the k highest and be done
  - if this not, make the secondary list your new primary list and goto (*)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the point suggested in the first bullet. Keeping the secondary list in the second bullet is not useful, because the element that would be queried next and number of queries would be the same in both cases.

Comment: @user1583688 The purpose of the secondary list is again to keep things small: It minimizes the steps necessary **apart** from calculating real value - splitting a sorted list is a very cheap operation, as is replacing a list by another